# Passing Data From Qt To Primitive Types In C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a button on a GUI written in Qt. What this button does is increasing an integer value by 2. This new value is then displayed in a widget on that same GUI. My goal is to pass this incremented value to a primitive data type, in this case and int.

The increment button allows you to increment a value which is displayed on the GUI, this means that I've used a SIGNAL and SLOT protocol between these two GUI elements.

SIGNAL and SLOT is different from action listener protocol and so, I can't seem to update the int I'm storing this value in per mouse button click. I need to be able to update this int value every time the user clicks the increment button on the GUI....the final goal is to pass this value to another mathematical function written elsewhere in C++. Below is my attempt at trying to figure out how to do just that. Note, the whole time the GUI runs, there is only one value printed out, that is the initial value stored in `outVal`. If this used action listeners then this would be a non-issue. So my question is, how do I update `outVal` every time there is a mouse click...thanks!

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSpinBox>

#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define MIN_WIDTH 350
#define MIN_HEIGHT 300

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    int outVal = 99;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    window.setMinimumSize(MIN_WIDTH,MIN_HEIGHT);


    QVBoxLayout * mainPlatter = new QVBoxLayout(&window);
    QSpinBox * spinBox = new QSpinBox;


    spinBox->setRange(1,77);
    spinBox->setSingleStep(2);






    QLabel * label = new QLabel("1");





    mainPlatter->addWidget(spinBox);;
    mainPlatter->addWidget(label);
    QObject :: connect( spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)) , label, SLOT(setNum(int)));



    outVal = spinBox->value();
    window.show();


    printf("%d\n",outVal);

    return a.exec();



    return 0;
}
```

Edit: After the advice i got, this is what i tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
using namespace std;

class Counter : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
     signals:
            void valueChanged(int newValue);
    public:
            Counter(){
                    m_value = 1;
            }
            int value() const {
                    return m_value;
            }
    public slots:
            void setValue(int value);
    private:
            int m_value;

 };
void Counter::setValue(int value){ 
    if(value != m_value){ 
            m_value = value;
            emit valueChanged(value);
    }

}
int main(void){
    Counter a, b;
    QObject :: connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    a.setValue(7);

    cout << "a.setValue(7) " << endl;
    cout << "(a.value, b.value) = " << a.value() << b.value() << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

these are my errors

g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o example1.o example1.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o gui1 example1.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
example1.o: In function `Counter::setValue(int)':
example1.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to`Counter::valueChanged(int)'
example1.o: In function `main':
example1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to`vtable for Counter'
example1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x94): undefined reference to `Counter::valueChanged(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gui1] Error 1

an FYI; I ran "qmake -project" then "qmake" then "make".

EDIT: The final working version! Moral of the story, put everything in its proper place using headers files, function definitions and drivers in separate c++ files, it makes life a lot easier when using QT. The specific issue here was the the MOC was not running since the driver(main) and the QObject class were in the same file.

```
//function.h
#ifndef FUNCTION_H
#define FUNCTION_H
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
            Counter(){
                    m_value = 1;
            }
            int value() const {
                    return m_value;
            }
    public slots:
            void setValue(int value);
    signals:
            void valueChanged(int newValue);
    private:
            int m_value;

};

#endif

//function.cpp
#include "function.h"
void Counter :: setValue(int value){ 
    if(value != m_value){ 
            m_value = value;
            emit valueChanged(value);
    }

}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>

#include "function.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void){
 Counter a, b;
    QObject :: connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    a.setValue(7);

    cout << "a.setValue(7) " << endl;
    cout << "(a.value, b.value) = " << a.value() << b.value() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The increment button allows you to increment a value which is displayed on the GUI, this means that ive *(sic)* used a SIGNAL and SLOT protocol between these two GUI elements

This is where the problem lies. What you should do is separate any data model from its visual representation. If you store the data in a class, let's call it Model, then connect the button to a slot in the Model class, the slot function can update its value and then emit a signal to update the view of the data.

For example:

```
class Model : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    signals:
        // connect this signal to the spin box setValue slot
        void UpdateView(int value);

    public slots:
        // connect this slot to the push button released() signal
        void IncrementValue();

    private:
        int m_value;
}

void Model::IncrementValue()
{
    m_value += 2;
    emit UpdateView(m_value);
}
```

There is a great design pattern that extends this called MVC ([Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

Comment: Very nice! So I see its up to me to implement the slots, what about the signals? We have defined UpdateView(int value), but how does that actually do anything?

Comment: You don't have to implement the SIGNAL - you just have to declare it. The rest is done by "Qt-magic", cp. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html resp. the Qt moc compiler, cp. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#moc

Comment: Im going to look deeper into MVC. As of now though, I cant compile this simple example. I spent a whole day looking through C++ stuff(I dont know the language really, im more of a C and Java person). Here is my code

Comment: If, as your code shows, the Counter class is in main.cpp, I think you need to manually #include the moc file for that class. Alternatively, move the Counter class to separate header and implementation files, clean the build, call qmake to rebuild the moc files and then compile the project.

Comment: @Merlin069 I've also tried putting everything in proper place using a header file, a file where i define functions and classes and a main file, same issues with the line of code "emit valueChanged(value)". And the auto generated moc file says to not include it with anything

Comment: Are you calling the emit from a function in the header?

Comment: Actually, it works now. I defined everything seperately( header, function definitions, driver), I had done it this way before but I seemed to have overlooked something, it works now. When using QT I think it makes life much easier to define eveything in its proper place(something I dont seem to do when working through examples)! To answer your question @Merlin069 , check out my original post, the working code is there!